# Ms-access database into visual basic

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, dataset

I have created Ms-access database using Microsoft office database. Database contain below elements

1. customer ID- Auto Number (datatype)
2. customer Name- text (datatype)
3. customer MobNo-  Number (datatype)
4. Mounting type -> text (datatype) followed by lookup table,

   ```
   look table -> roof mount , ground mount,pitched mount
   ```
5. Country ->text(datatype) followed by lookup table,

   ```
   lookup table -> various country
   ```

I am using this Ms-access table in visual basic project form.Problem i am facing now

I can access these data in windows form.The element which is having  Country , mounting type are lookup table.when i drop in the form they appear to be text. 
How can make it appear as lookup table in windows form

Whether i need to use combobox or i can make the box itself has lookup table.